# Threads, Concurrency, and examples of use

Tags: multithreading, theory

I'm just trying to satisfy my curiosity. So I've just learned about threading and concurrency, and I'm just curious about in what applications would they be good for? Some examples I've found are of countdowns, pauses, etc. I'd just like to know more about how they could work and in what ways they are used. Any knowledge is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In java, you can look at Servlet API, RMI, Timer etc. All these are applications of concurrency.

Comment: Service jobs that are implemented to do interval based on work on backend servers are usually built in a way that the jobs ride on the back of a job thread pulled from a custom thread pool via a custom thread pool controller. This allows multiple service workers to run on an as needed basis and in parallel. Priorities can be applied to important jobs so they can finish sooner or have more cycles in a given timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that it can be applied to a lot of video games because of the huge amount of calculations and processes needed. They are also very useful for things like vector math and advanced arithmetic methods because of the number of calculations needed for the current function, or method in the calculation.